# Get id of row inserted into database

Tags: database

I insert data into database table using query builder:

```
$command = Craft::$app->db->createCommand()->insert('test2', array());
$command->execute();
```

How can i retrieve `id` of newly inserted db row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can use `getLastInsertID` to fetch the ID:

```
Craft::$app->db->getLastInsertID();
```

Comment: This causes `Calling unknown method: craft\db\Command::getLastInsertID()` error. I searched craft docs for this function and it is in `craft\db\pgsql` - i use mysql.

Comment: Ah, I meant to write `Craft::$app->db->getLastInsertID();`. That'll teach me to cut and paste quickly, my apologies. Give that a try.

Comment: Unfortunately i still get `Calling unknown method: craft\db\Command::getLastInsertID()` error.

Comment: Actually, it worked! But is it possible that it returns wrong value? For example if two db inserts are performed in nearly same time.

Comment: I've wondered about that too. Honestly, I don't know, but I think that PHP's single-threaded nature would mean it's very unlikely (if not impossible) that another insert could happen between the two lines of your code.